# How do I launch shell applications after changing shell to MacPorts bash?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, bash, macports

I have installed a current bash version via MacPorts and changed Terminal.app to use `/opt/local/bin/bash`. Unfortunately shell applications won't launch from Finder and Spotlight anymore. (OSX 10.8.2, Bash 4.2.37)

Comment: Which shell applications? Can you give an example or some additional info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just changed the login shell and left Terminal's settings unchanged.

1. Set the shells open with setting back to the default login shell in Terminal's preferences
2. Add `/opt/local/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells`
3. `chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash`
4. Open a new tab and check `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: This did the trick for me. Strange enough, the GUI (`Preferences > Users & Groups > right click on account`) does not show the shell added to `/etc/shells`. Thus, only `chsh` works here for me.